# neural network model doesn't work

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

```
import numpy as np
temp_data_x = np.random.randn(200,3)
temp_data_y = temp_data_x[:,0] + temp_data_x[:,1] + temp_data_x[:,2] + np.random.randn(200,1).reshape(200,)
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
net = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(3),  activation='tanh', max_iter=1000,
  learning_rate_init=0.1,verbose=True, random_state=3)
net1 = net.fit(temp_data_x[0:150,],temp_data_y[0:150])
net.coefs_[0][0:5,0:5]
net1.coefs_[0][0:5,0:5]
net.predict(temp_data_x[199,].reshape(1,-1))
net1.predict(temp_data_x[199,].reshape(1,-1))
```

I made and ran this simple neural network using python numpy and scikit learn,
but the coefficients and predicted values from the initial model (net) and fitted model (net1) are identical.
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

To answer to the question on why you are getting same coefficients and predictions using the variable net and net1, is because both of them are references to same object.
To check that, you can run this:

```
print(net is net1)
```

You will get `True`. The reason for that is you have already created the reference for your `MLPRegressor` object. So when you `fit` the model with values of X and y, the model of `net` will try to fit into the provided value and then assign the same object to `net1`.

Next, I believe you have to reduce your learning rate (say 0.01) for it to learn better or at least for your neural network to fit into the provided data.

Lastly, as you may have already checked, your model may not perform better on the values outside your test data as your data is random data.

**Edit:**

Based on the request to print the learned weights(coefficients) after each round of epoch, I am adding the extra details. As it is with [MLPRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html#sklearn-neural-network-mlpregressor), you will not be able to print the details of learned weights after each iteration/batch etc. For that you will have to make use of [sknn.mlp](http://scikit-neuralnetwork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module_mlp.html#sknn-mlp-multi-layer-perceptrons) module. They have a variety of [callbacks](http://scikit-neuralnetwork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide_learning.html#customizing-learning) which can be used to print/evaluate your learning time to time.

Consider the code below to get you started:

```
def print_coeff_callback(**variables):
    print('End of epoch: {}'.format(variables['i']))
    print('Layer 0: Weights:')
    print(variables['best_params'][0][0])
    print('Layer 0: Biases:')
    print(variables['best_params'][0][1])
    print('Layer 1: Weights:')
    print(variables['best_params'][1][0])
    print('Layer 1: Biases:')
    print(variables['best_params'][1][1])
    print()

import numpy as np
temp_data_x = np.random.randn(200,3)
temp_data_y = temp_data_x[:,0] + temp_data_x[:,1] + temp_data_x[:,2]\
    + np.random.randn(200,1).reshape(200,)

from sknn.mlp import Regressor, Layer
net = Regressor(layers = [Layer('Tanh', units = 3), Layer('Linear', units = 1)], 
                learning_rate = 0.01, n_iter = 10,
               verbose = True, random_state = 3,
                callback = {'on_epoch_finish': print_coeff_callback})
net.fit(temp_data_x[0:150,],temp_data_y[0:150])
```

When you run this code, at the end of each epoch, you will be getting additional details like this:

```
End of epoch: 1
Layer 0: Weights:
[[-0.50751932 -0.72378025 -0.37128063]
 [-0.53206593 -0.33147215  0.83072845]
 [-0.66474313 -0.76372327 -0.85991181]]
Layer 0: Biases:
[-0.03277463 -0.10826231  0.01669442]
Layer 1: Weights:
[[-0.88015991]
 [-1.13531142]
 [ 0.06633887]]
Layer 1: Biases:
[ 0.16668694]

End of epoch: 2
Layer 0: Weights:
[[-0.49187796 -0.70438651 -0.36641678]
 [-0.66897643 -0.51718653  0.83213911]
 [-0.68042139 -0.72434914 -0.85017705]]
Layer 0: Biases:
[ 0.09687692  0.04577672  0.00219902]
Layer 1: Weights:
[[-1.11614207]
 [-1.31741563]
 [-0.02267721]]
Layer 1: Biases:
[ 0.02075817]
```

As you can see, the details of learned weights/biases are present and they are changing time to time.

Comment: so you mean the initial model 'net' is overwritten by 'net1.' Then how can I keep the 'net' model unchanged? So that I can compare?

Comment: Actually I have to add another observations to the current data set and compare models 'net1' and 'net2.'

Comment: If I implement the same pseudocode in R or MATLAB, the model 'net' should remain the same even though I fit model 'net1.' What does python work like this?

Comment: I am asking this because I have to keep the model 'net1' unchanged and create other models 'net2' repeatedly and compare them..

Comment: @user67275  I have modified my answer to print the learned weights after every epoch.

Comment: @user67275 you can store the values of weights/biases or other variables like loss etc after each epoch and then compare them at the end. Hope this answer helps you. Let me know if you need more details.